# fast_executemany=True throwing DBAPIError: Function sequence error in sqlalchemy version 1.3.5

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

Since **SQLAlchemy 1.3.0, released 2019-03-04,**

sqlalchemy now supports 
`engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url, fast_executemany=True)` 
for the `mssql+pyodbc` dialect. I.e.,

it is no longer necessary to define a function and use

```
@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute').
```

However when i am trying to write a simple test dataframe to **mssql** it returns error:

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLParamData)')
>   [SQL: INSERT INTO fast_executemany_test ([Date], [A], [B], [C], [D]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)][parameters: ((datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 3, 0, 0), 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 'Joe'), (datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 4, 0, 0), 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 'Joe'), (datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5, 0, 0), 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 'Pete'), (datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 6, 0, 0), 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 'Mary'))]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)

I have gone through the documentation but could not find what am I doing wrong.

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

DataFrame contains datetime, float, float, float, string. 

test_columns = ['Date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
test_data = [
    [datetime(2018, 1, 3), 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 'Joe'],
    [datetime(2018, 1, 4), 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 'Joe'],
    [datetime(2018, 1, 5), 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 'Pete'],
    [datetime(2018, 1, 6), 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 'Mary'],
]

I am establishing connection as:

sqlUrl='mssql+pyodbc://ID:PASSWORD' + 'SERVER_ADDRESS' + '/' + 'DBName' + '?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

sqlcon = sqlalchemy.create_engine(sqlUrl,fast_executemany=True)

if sqlcon:
    test_data.to_sql('FastTable_test', sqlcon, if_exists='replace',index=False)
    print('Successfully written!')

It creates the table but due to error does not write any data into it.
```

Comment: Looks like a pyodbc/sqla issue. PyODBC issue tracker has multiple issues about this error, in relation to fast executemany.